# Get coordinates from geojson with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, geojson

I'm trying to export area names and borders from geojson to csv. Here's the sample of my data:

```
{
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "features" : [{
     "type":"Feature",
        "properties" : {
           "id"            : "72639",
           "alltags"       : {
              "name:en" : "Area1",
              "admin_level" : "4"}
           },
           "geometry": {"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[36.407,45.071],[36.408,45.072],[36.406,45.071],[36.407,45.071]]],[[[35.082,45.611],[35.084,45.605],[35.082,45.611],[35.082,45.611]]]]}
        },{
     "type":"Feature",
        "properties" : {
           "id"            : "71245",
           "alltags"       : {
              "name:en" : "Area2",
              "admin_level" : "4"}
           },
           "geometry": {"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.189,50.625],[29.196,51.607],[27.195,50.561],[27.190,50.624],[27.189,50.625]]]]}
        } ]
}
```

I want to get output with 'name:en' and coordinates like this:

```
Area1
[[[[36.407,45.071],[36.408,45.072],[36.406,45.071],[36.407,45.071]]],[[[35.082,45.611],[35.084,45.605],[35.082,45.611],[35.082,45.611]]]]
Area2
[[[[27.189,50.625],[29.196,51.607],[27.195,50.561],[27.190,50.624],[27.189,50.625]]]]
```

I use following script:

```
$path = "D:\!map\!test\"
$name_in = "test.GeoJson"
$coords_pattern = '"value":(.*?),"Count"'

$inputjson = Get-Content -Raw -Path $path$name_in | ConvertFrom-Json
Foreach ($feature in $inputjson.features){
   $area_name = $feature.properties.alltags.'name:en'
   $geojson = $feature.geometry
   $coordinates = $geojson.coordinates | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
   $borders = [regex]::match($coordinates, $coords_pattern).Groups[1].Value
   Write-Host $area_name
   Write-Host $borders
}
```

For Area2 everything is OK, but Area1 consists of 2 groups of coordinates and output for Area1 is 'broken':

```
Area1
[["36.407 45.071","36.408 45.072","36.406 45.071","36.407 45.071"]]
Area2
[[[27.189,50.625],[29.196,51.607],[27.195,50.561],[27.190,50.624],[27.189,50.625]]]
```

In real data, areas could have unknown number of that coordinates group. How can I get correct set of coordinates?

Comment: this >>> `$InStuff.features[0].properties.alltags.'name:en' <<< will give you the name of the 1st feature. then this >>> `$InStuff.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][0][0]` <<< will give you the 1st pair of coords in that shape. you can iterate thru it and rebuild it into whatever pattern you want at that point. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps simpler using `-replace`:

```
$inputjson = $geo | ConvertFrom-Json
Foreach ($feature in $inputjson.features){
   $area_name = $feature.properties.alltags.'name:en'
   $geojson = $feature.geometry
   $coordinates = ($geojson.coordinates | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 4) -replace '\{"value":|,"Count":1\}|"', ''
   Write-Host $area_name
   Write-Host $coordinates
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Area1
> [[[[36.407,45.071],[36.408,45.072],[36.406,45.071],[36.407,45.071]]],[[[35.082,45.611],[35.084,45.605],[35.082,45.611],[35.082,45.611]]]]
> Area2
> [[[27.189,50.625],[29.196,51.607],[27.195,50.561],[27.190,50.624],[27.189,50.625]]]
> ```

<sup>I have no idea how deep the nestings of the coordinate arrays can go, so you'll have to play with the `-Depth` parameter on the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Looks like for my data use of 'replace' is enough.

Comment: Nice one (+1). You *could* cram that into a one line and store to file: `((gc D:\!map\!test\test.geojson)|convertfrom-json).features|%{$_.properties.alltags.'name:en';($_.geometry.coordinates|ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 4) -replace '\{"value":|,"Count":1\}|"'}|set-content new.geojson`

Comment: Or make an Object and store that into a csv file: `((gc D:\!map\!test\test.geojson)|convertfrom-json).features|%{[PSCustomObject]@{'Area'=$_.properties.alltags.'name:en';'Coordinates'=(($_.geometry.coordinates | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 4) -replace '\{"value":|,"Count":1\}|"')}}|Export-Csv -NoT geojson.csv`

Comment: And a small note from me. "Count" could be more than 1, so I changed string with replace to: $coordinates = ($geojson.coordinates | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 4) -replace '\{"value":|,"Count":[0-9]*\}|"', ''

Comment: @AndreyBaulin Good point! That never crossed my mind. Maybe even better to use `\d+` instead of `[0-9]*`.